# How to reliably kill a port on crash in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

What is the best practice to reliably kill a port created by open_port?

```
Port = open_port({spawn,"yes"},[binary]),

% use Port and clash 
% leak process

mykill(Port),
```

Comment: Does [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13909943/409228) help?

Comment: Thank you.
But I want to know how to avoid leaks even when crashing!

Comment: Do you mean Erlang process crash or Erlang node (OS process) crash?

Comment: Erlang process crash

Comment: You can `link/1` to ports from any process (both have to be node-local). The port is automatically linked to the process that started it, so if this process (or any linked process) crashes, the port closes

Answer (score 1):

You can `link/1` to ports from any process (both have to be node-local). The port is automatically linked to the process that started it, so if this process exits or any linked process crashes, the port closes.

Comment: But if I set `yes` to `sleep 10000`, the os process survives.

Comment: @fuyutsubaki the port closes, and so does the pipe connecting it to the external process. That's the extent Erlang is supposed to go automatically (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67704043/erlang-how-to-make-connected-external-os-process-automatically-die-when-control)). If you want to actually send a SIGTERM OS signal to the OS process, you need to do it manually (or you can have the OS process blocked reading stdin and exiting on EPIPE)